# method to generate test data from real source database in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, test-data, data-generation

I have production database inOracle 11g - entire schema.
How can I use this to generate test data (all values garbled) with relationships maintained, (only string vales garbled not ids or numbers for example)
Is there a tool to do this like data generator or we can do this manually easily?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

see 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_obtoo2.htm
http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/data-masking-best-practices-161213.pdf
http://test.techwell.com/sites/default/files/articles/XUS304776788file1_0.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using simple SQL queries to generate data. For example consider the query below.

```
SELECT 'ORACLE' || ROWNUM ID,
       DEPT_CD,
       ACCT_NO,
       TITLE,
       NO_OF_SUBORDN,
       ANNUAL_SALARY,
       CUBICLE_ID,
       DATE_OF_JOINING,
       V_CCY_CODE
  FROM (SELECT TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(100, 1000)) DEPT_CD,
               TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 20)) NO_OF_SUBORDN,
               TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(20000, 200000), 2) ANNUAL_SALARY,
               DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('U', 10) || ' / ' ||
               TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(100, 1000)) CUBICLE_ID,
               SYSDATE + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(-365 * 15, -1) DATE_OF_JOINING
          FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100) TBL1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT V_CCY_CODE
                     FROM DIM_CURRENCY
                    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) TBL2 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ACCT_NO, TITLE
                     FROM DIM_ACCOUNT
                    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) TBL3 ON 1 = 1
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE;
```

In this query, the random data is generated using the DBMS_RANDOM package in TBL1. 
Data from DIM tables or lookup tables can be brought in using the cartesian join as shown in TBL2 and TBL3.

Note: Keep the LEVEL in TBL1 to a minimum as a cartesian join is being made with the other tables and so the resultant dataset wil be huge.